# Create Pagination for data received from API

Tags: php, curl, pagination

I want to create pagination to the listing received from Curl API.

```
 <?php 

 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "http://testurl.org/news_posting?page=1&length=1",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Authorization: Bearer $final_token"
 ),
));

 $responses = curl_exec($curl);
 $data = json_decode($responses, true);
 $total_data_count = count($data['data']);
?>
```

Now i want to show pagination below this and change the page number in the url dynamically (page=1) based on the pagination selected.

Thanks for all your help and support.

Comment: pagination works only if you know what page you are on and how many pages there are, the response has to give you some information regarding this

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got my answer and want to share with you all.

```
 <?php
 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "http://testurl.org/news_posting?page=1&length=1",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
 "Authorization: Bearer $final_token"
 ),
 ));

 $responses = curl_exec($curl);
 $data = json_decode($responses, true);
 $total_jobs_posted_pagi = count($data['data']);



  $pages_pagi = (ceil($total_jobs_posted_pagi / $select_postnumber));
  
  $pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>";  

 $prev_page = $pagenumber_pagi-1;
 $next_page = $pagenumber_pagi+1;
  if ($pagenumber_pagi > 1) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url; ?>/test3.php?page=<?php echo $prev_page; ?>"> 
     &laquo; </a>

   <?php } 

  for ($i=1; $i<=$pages_pagi; $i++) {  
         $pagLink .= "<a href='$site_url/test3.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
    };  

     echo $pagLink . "</div>";  

    if ($pagenumber_pagi < $pages_pagi) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $site_url; ?>/test3.php?page=<?php echo $next_page; ?>"> 
    &raquo; </a>

<?php }   
  
   $pagenumber_pagi = $_GET['page'];


  $curl = curl_init();

   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "http://testurl.org/news_posting?page=$pagenumber_pagi&length=$select_postnumber",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Authorization: Bearer $final_token"
  ),
));

?>
```